# Putting windows 8 onto a new hybrid drive, using preinstalled windows from a new computer onto a clean SSHD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, sshd, hybrid-storage

The question is: I'm buying a new laptop with an HDD in it, which has Windows 8 preinstalled. I want to exchange the drive HDD with a Hybrid drive (SSHD). The SSHD will mostelikely be the  [Seagate STBD1000400 1TB + 8GB SSD 5400 RPM 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 2.5" Internal Hybrid Hard Drive Retail Kit](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178384)

I want to convert Windows 8 on to my SSHD with it working successfully, without having to buy a new Windows 8. I researched on cloning it with a system image, but would that make my SSHD work to the best of its ability? Will windows 8 be automatically stored on the SSD part of my SSHD? Will windows manage to make my SSDH function and effectively store the most accesed file son the SSD part?

I researched on the internet, however not many people where of the same opinion and quite contradicting for example in the following [chat](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3386743)

Comment: Your OEM license is connected to firmware level storage.  Windows 8 will automatically detect your key, or you can prior to that, grab it using any number of tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how the Hybrid Drives work. Instead, do a normal cloning of your Windows 8 on to the Hybrid drive. Over time, it will recache the data onto the SSD portion. I would suggest rebooting 5 times in a row to begin the caching build. There really isn't any kind of management software for these hybrid drives. The drive then "learns" you usage patterns and caches the most frequently accessed data on the SSD. It's most beneficial if you use the same programs over and over. If you perform a variety of tasks, then you won't see much improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on users, go to the source, Seagate. There you will find the most reliable information regarding your hybrid hard drive and any special tuning it may require. Contact Seagate and explain you have a pre-purchase question, and you will get a straight answer.